# Error while trying to use AngularJS service as a constructor function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The idea is to hide/show empty inputs clicking on the headers above.
I need the same functionality throughout many scopes so decided to use `angular.service` as a constructor.

**ng-click** expression is supposed to be instantiated in its scope with service function but after being clicked it shows that it's not a function.

Can anyone please help me with it?

*expected behavior you can see by clicking on `Driver` block header from the example below (`Car` and `Info` not working because of that error)

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/x0TbT5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution found is to describe desired behavior in the AngularJS `directive` and assign it to the block where it is needed.
[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/b10DqQ?p=preview)